# singularities preserved by integral closure

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, birational-geometry

Let $X$ be an affine variety. Let $A$ be the coordinate ring of $X$ and let $K$ be the fraction field of $A$.  Given a Galois extension $K\subset L$, let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. Let $Y$ be the associated affine variety of $B$.

Questions:  can rational (Gorenstein) singularities be inherited from $X$ to $Y$?

Comment: Generally there is no hope that things like this can be true.  Under some conditions (if $Y \to X$ is etale in codimension 1 for example) then if $X$ is log terminal then so is $Y$.  This kind of statement does *not* hold for rational singularities though.  Although in the Gorenstein case, rational singularities are equivalent to log terminal singularities... (and log terminal always implies rational).

Comment: Thanks. Could you give some relevant references?  I'm not quite aware of some standard AG terminology,  what do you mean by etale in codimension 1? Maybe you mean etale outside a codimension 2 subvariety?

Comment: Yup, I mean etale outside a codimension 2 subvariety.  Perhaps the right reference is Kollar-Mori for the statement I cited.  For rational singularities though this is false, see for instance the work of Anurag K. Singh on canonical covers of rational singularities.